# dplyr::bind_rows(...) vs. do.call(rbind, ...) for lists of symbols

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Suppose I have the below data frames and character vector of names:

```
x <- data.frame(val = 1)
y <- data.frame(val = 2)
nms <- c("x", "y")
```

I want to simply row bind the data frames together. I can do this with `do.call` and `rbind` without issue:

```
library(dplyr)

do.call(rbind, syms(nms))
#  val
#1   1
#2   2
```

However if I try `dplyr::bind_rows` I get a strange error telling me that argument 1 must be a data frame event though it is a data frame:

```
bind_rows(syms(nms))
#Error: Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a data.frame
```

Would appreciate if someone could tell *why* this occurs.

Comment: what is the need for `syms()` in `bind_rows()`? If you try, `bind_rows(x,y)` it will work. Also see this github [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2962)

Comment: There isn't really a need, as this problem can be solved a lot of ways. I was just curious why `bind_rows` was failing here as I expected it to work and the error was cryptic and the `traceback` pointed to C code which wasn't illuminating. Looks like that github issue (mostly) answers my question though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mget` to return the datasets in a `list` and then do the `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
mget(nms) %>%
   bind_rows
#  val
#1   1
#2   2
```